# How can I avoid pitfalls passing the finished product to the install team?

Tags: deployment, communication

Anyone out there have any experience with passing off a finished product to the install team?

Our product is installable via RPMs but also requires copying some MySQL data, modifying some config files and running a few development written scripts.  Having an install team is great, but it is development that is on-call and after each install we get calls from the customer after hours that we have to support.

We do learn from each incident, but it would be good for our customers, our reputation and my sleep to be a bit more proactive.

Specifically:

- What tools have you used to improve
  communication/collaboration between
  the teams?
- What technical solutions have you used?
- What policies have you used?
- Has anyone had any success with writing post-install validation tools?

**Edit:**
I should clarify that I'm not talking about software failures that development and/or QA should have caught.  The problem is calls from the customer saying "Option A isn't available all of a sudden" because it wasn't configured to be on, or "I can't log on" because the authentication server is not configured correctly.

Comment: *facepalm* *facepalm* *facepalm*

Comment: @Robert: Give malfist a break. He heard virtual machines were good, and now he is going to spread that to every place he can to try and look intelligent.

Comment: Subjective and arugmentative?? Whoever voted this way - please lock your computer while you're away, your cat is obviously on your desk and clicking on links.

Comment: @Rich B, Virtual Machines are good for testing in isolated environments. However, I did not read the question well, and thought the OP was doing the testing. When I realized I was wrong, I removed the comment.

Comment: /me pats malfist's head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically Assaf's answer with different emphasis.
Having been on both sides of deployments, there are two major items to ENSURE a good deployment.

---

1. **Few moving parts**

This means, if you have an option of giving a few files and having the deployer put them in certain folders on the production environment, or you could pre-place the files in the folder structure, and have the deployer just copy it into the root. Or even easier, a batch file. Or an MSI. If they have to run SQL scripts, then clearly show where they are.

Basically, this step boils down to allowing the developer to create scripts and batch files, and automate as much as humanly (heh) possible. That way, the deployer (who does not know the app as well as you do) isn't expected to mind-read what they are supposed to do with the three files left over. (Duh, you're supposed to place them in folders A, B, D and ZZ)

---

2. **DEPLOYMENT GUIDE**

That's all in caps because it trumps step one. I am talking about a VERY thorough guide.

It shouldn't say

"*move the Map-related files into the Map-App-Data folder.*"

It should say

"*Move *files x,y,z* (located in *folder X* in your deployment package) to the Map-App-Data folder (located *D:\AppName\Map-App-Data*)*".

Go through the motions of even saying "Remote in to X server, then do y" because you might think it's clear which server the deployer should be on, but for multi-server setups, it's can get pretty sticky as to what should be done where. Given a document this thorough means that anyone can deploy, even someone who you haven't had the chance to train as to what is happening.

---

2.1 **Rollback plan**

Put the rollback plan right into the deployment guide. If a deployment goes wrong, and they occasionally will, you don't want to leave the server offline until the deployer is able to wake someone up who knows what's going on. It should be there right in front of them. Even if it seems obvious and simple to you, remember that you've just spent the last four weeks engrossed in this project, and this person has spent the last 20 minutes. They simply can't be exptected to know what you don't tell them.

---

2.2 **Test the deployment guide**

Go through the steps yourself. Or better yet, get a colleague who is NOT on the project to try deploying to UAT with your guide, and you sitting next to them. Anywhere they get it wrong, change the guide. Anywhere the deployment goes wrong (situations you've seen before) add a footnote in the guide that explains why this situation occurs, and how to fix it if possible. It is critically important that your deployment guide not have errors, because when you write the deployment guide, then you are essentially doing to the deployment (because you know how) AND you get the bonus of sleeping through it. But, it also means that any mistakes are on you.

Please add comments for anything I've missed, and I'll toss it in.

Answer (score 1):

Not targeting your specific questions, but once-upon-a-time there was a team of developers and testers deploying a web application to a set of servers for testing and verification.

When it was time for release the customer got the deployable files and deployed it as per specifications ... To a set of servers nothing alike our development servers.

There was a massive influx of bugs, chaos ensued, the customer raged and the poor developers didn't get to sleep.

My tip is one of the most obvious; make sure the development environment matches the production environment to avoid environment specific bugs.

Comment: So you're recommending to not make your program flexible, and instead make it bound to a specific setup?

Comment: Sounds good... you then release your program as a self-executable virtual machine image that can run in a seamless mode on the host environment and it can act as though it's machine is the same as it's development machine :)

Comment: In a project where you can sell your project to multiple customers, no. That would be shooting yourself in the foot.

In a project that is ordered by the customer, paid for by the customer and will be deployed on the customers servers. Yes, I'd recommend anyone to make the program to work perfectly on the customers specific setup above all else. The customer will not be any happier if you say "It may not work on your environment, but on <em>ours</em> it's great.".

Comment: @varl, you just stated why you should make it flexible, so it can work on both your system and your customers system.
@workmad3, lol. That'd be a mess.

Comment: @Malfist Who will pay for the time that you spend to make sure it works on different setups? Who will pay for the time it takes to verify and resolve issues on different setups? Who will pay for the testers needed to verify and flush out bugs on different setups? The customer? No, the customer will not want to pay for the ego boost developers get from knowing that one has flexible code. Especially not these days.

Comment: In defense of Varl:  Because our product requires dedicated servers, we can guarantee the OS (eg RH ES4) that the product is run on.  As such, developers are required to ensure the code runs correctly on that OS and QA tests on that OS.

Comment: The point is that we, the suppliers, messed up. We should have had the same setup as our customer since this is a custom built solution for the customer; i.e. the customer pays for literally everything and while some are inclined to be fast and loose with other peoples money, that doesn't fly in times as these.

Comment: @Varl, what happens when your customers move to a different system?

Comment: @Robert, I'm not talking about flexibility of OS's, that's a HUGE difference. I'm talking about using IIS instead of Apache, or the database being in a specific location. Differences sure, but not major. As a customer I wouldn't want the program to blow up because I moved the database to a cluster, and the application could only work if the database was on localhost. Or if I wanted to host my data like images and video's on Amazon and the program wanted it to be on /var/www/images

Comment: Oh. I was writing a long reply about what will happen if the customer wanted to run on another platform, but after that last comment I see that you and I are thinking in vastly different scopes. This project is a multi-million investment, live in over a dozen countries and scheduled for global expansion over the next few years. The application relies on Akamai for distributing content. Trivial things as changing paths, web server platform etc will never be an issue... There is no "changing system" as you would see it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Some ground rules:

1. Always deliver the product signed and sealed. Use zip (or anything that has checksum), don't deliver individual files or directories.
2. Burn it on a CD and physically hand it over. That way you'll *know* you have a hard copy (and a backup) that works. You'd be amazed how easy it is to screw up an installation because of CD burners that corrupt files silently.
3. The install team (or QA) should receive exactly what the customer receives, nothing less. Assume they know less about your product than the dumbest customer.
4. Naturally you should always keep a repository of all such deliveries cataloged by version.
5. Print any installation/deployment/user guide that comes with the version and physically hand it over. As paper. Even if the document did not change since last version. I have wasted a lot of time helping QA debug an installation and later realizing they were using the wrong installation guide.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't have an "install team". The developers should be responsible for developing a working system, not a pile of pieces that they throw over the wall for some other poor saps to get working.
- Have a fully automated deployment/upgrade process. Deployment should require *no* manual decision making because someone will one day accidentally make the wrong decision.
- If a deployment fails, fix the automation and re-release. Don't kludge the system into production in-place, because people will one day forget to check the fixes back into the source code repository.
- Test the deployment/upgrade process regularly during development. Preferably on every commit, as part of the continuous integration process.
- Ensure that the test environment is as close to production as possible. Ideally the only difference should be passwords.
- Run environment tests as part of the deployment. I usually implement these in the system itself, so that it self-tests and reports what is wrong with its runtime environment.
- Make it easy to roll back failed deployments.

Comment: @Nat - Thanks for the reply, however, 1) Eliminating the install team would cut one point of failure, but it would require the developers to become experts in installing OS's and network configuration, and take time away from actual development.  2) We hardly throw a pile of pieces over a wall, we have a fully tested and QA'd, RPM installable application that requires some hand configuration.  Each customer is different, so we need to find a way to make sure the configuration is done correctly.

Comment: Note, I did not say you should get rid of the people. I said you should get rid of having a separate team.  The two teams is a bottleneck for communication and learning. You've got programmers  who write code but aren't involved in making it smoothly deployable and so aren't learning as quickly as they could about all the platforms and environments they have to deploy into. You've got an install team who can't change the software to make it easier for them to work with. You need to break down the barrier between programmers and "installers" so that people can more efficiently cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion, it was our build team that came up with the idea of using something called Jump Start.  We can package our RPMs and any necessary configuration (MySQL commands, changes to httpd.conf, etc...).  Once we encounter a problem with an install, we can modify the script; this pretty much guarantees that the same mistake will not be made twice.

I'll update once we actually start using this live.