# How to alert the support team when the newly deployed application has some issues

Tags: java, unix, jsf-2, production-environment, weblogic-10.x

My question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917576/how-can-i-avoid-pitfalls-passing-the-finished-product-to-the-install-team)

We are going to deploy a new application in the oracle weblogic server installed in UNIX. The details of the development that we are using in dev & production are given below.

Env that we use for Development:
JSF - front end
Log4J - loggin 
Oracle web logic server - Server
DB - Oracle.

Production Environment:
Creating WAR file from the development and deploy in in the weblogic server installed in UNIX Machine.

Problem:
The team who is gonna deploy the application in production is expecting an alert from the application whenever the app is unable service the request or say some exception happened. Any kind of unexpected error or situation happens that needs to be alerted to the production support team.

By this the team will make sure the application runs successfully with out any pitfalls.

On programmatic level I can catch the exceptions in the log, but how can I able to alert the prod support team when there is something wrong went with the application?

Please let know your suggestions or advise to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Logging frameworks like Log4J or Logback are able to send emails in case of warn or error level messages.